# Should all programmers know how to solve algorithms, etc

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm 15 and have been programming for about 3-4 years. I mostly program in Java as it was my first language.

I would like to be a programmer when I'm older, but I'm not sure about the differences. I've used a website, named hackerrank.com, and struggled immensely on the EASY questions. I can program games, applications, etc. But solving algorithms on this website is extremely difficult for me. If I were to be a programmer, would I have to be able to solve extremely difficult algorithms, or not? I understand Computer Scientists would have to, but a back-end game developer, or application developer for large aviation companies need to?

Comment: career advice is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Comment: You're 15.  In three years go to college and get a CS degree.  Assuming it's a half decent school, you'll get plenty of practice with algorithms there.  With your experience, you'll have a head start compared to some (the ones that didn't also start programming when you did).  Good luck.

Comment: You mentioned two career tracks, and these two particular career tracks have moderate to high requirements on algorithms. As others explained, you will probably need a college degree for these. On the other hand, there are career tracks with lower requirements (day-to-day relevance) on algorithms. In general, the first two years of a CS college education should be very useful for anyone working on software.

Comment: You don't solve algorithms, you use them ;) It's an important distinction.

Comment: I would suggest you to: learn some other programming language (e.g. [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) with [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)..., Ocaml, Scala, Prolog, ...); install and use Linux; study some free software; have your life (playing, sports, friends, ...); be good in math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I were to be a programmer, would I have to be able to solve extremely difficult algorithms, or not?

Maybe, maybe not. There are many professional programmers who do nothing noteworthy, yet are still employed (and horrible).

> I understand Computer Scientists would have to, but a back-end game developer, or application developer for large aviation companies need to?

Absolutely. If anything, skilled developers in these fields will face even more challenging problems, because they won't nearly be so well defined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many developers, especially in challenging fields such as video games or avionics, have to solve challenging logical and computing problems all day long. If this does not suit your taste or if you tend to have lesser logical capacities *than people of your age with equivalent experience*, then programming may not be for you. You could still run a modest career on modest/dirty projects but it could be fairly boring and I would exclude challenging fields.

However please note that at 15 your cognition capacities are still incomplete, that experience will help a lot and that programming **is** difficult anyway. Even more at the beginning. Besides you may be less experienced than you think you are: you claim that you have programmed since a few years but you should better evaluate the number of actual hours spent programming and convert this into weeks of full-time studies/work.

Answer (score 1):

To be a normal developer (by normal I mean someone who just takes requirement from senior developer/architect, and do according to instruction), you will not need deep knowledge in algorithm. 
However to advance further in technical side, I believe (my opinion only) that understanding of various algorithms, data structures is necessary. You may not need to remember how to implement all the algorithms, but at least have ideas of what it is and it is used in what situation, so you can apply it (or look up it in internet) when necessary. E.g. when you optimize the code for faster execution, etc

Answer (score 0):

I've found that for the most part, in an everyday business setting, the programming you do isn't really complicated.  Usually no where near the difficulty of problems found in text books or competitions.  Most of the complicated algorithms you need are provided for you in libraries.  That being said, it is also true that most generic business problems are not the most interesting.  If you are looking to solve the tough problems, you will need to learn as much math as possible.